# IDEA and Eclipse : How to automatic generate method when extends a class

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, extends

My question is extremely easy when you implement a class. (because Eclipse and IDEA can generate for us).

But, I don't know how to do the same when you extends a class. (Of course this work is not must, but I want to be sure what to do in my code, so this option will be helpful).

thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Eclipse, go into the Source menu (`Alt+Shift+s`) -> Override/Implement Methods... and this should give you a list of all the methods that can be @overriden.

Comment: CMD + Option + S on Mac

Answer (score 6):

In IntelliJ : <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>  shows the list of methods to override/implement

Answer (score 4):

In IntelliJ: <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Insert</kbd> generates all kinds of code, including overriding methods, implementing methods, constructors, getters, setters, delegators and so on.