# Generate overide methods in intellij idea

Tags: android, intellij-idea

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IDEA and Eclipse : How to automatic generate method when extends a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425338/idea-and-eclipse-how-to-automatic-generate-method-when-extends-a-class)

I just switch from eclipse to intellij idea. Cause its much faster and i like the single workspace per project. My question is how to generate methods in intellij? like in eclipse you will right click in the editor and will navigate like this

[image]

How to do that in intellij? Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ctrl + O (override methods) and Ctrl + I (implements methods) are what you are looking for :)

Here is the cheat sheet

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf

Good luck :)

Comment: also you can press Alt+Insert to find all the available action for the current class you are in including overriding methods, getter/setters and the toString method